# CLSQL: Locally enabling sql reader syntax

Tags: common-lisp, clsql

I am trying to use the trivial SELECT in CLSQL. I tried many permutations, as shown below:

```
(clsql:select 'dept_name
              :from 'dept
              :where (= 'dept_id 1))
;; Error 
;; DEPT_ID is not of type NUMBER 
;; though dept_id is of type INTEGER

(clsql:select 'dept_name
              :from 'dept
              :where [= id 'dept_id])
;; Error
;; The variable [= is unbound.
;;    [Condition of type UNBOUND-VARIABLE]

(clsql:select [dept.dept_name]
             :from [dept]
             :where [= [dept.dept_id] 2])
;; Error
;; The variable [DEPT.DEPT_NAME] is unbound.

(clsql:select 'dept
              :where [= [slot-value 'dept 'dept-id] 1])

;; Error
;; The variable [= is unbound.
;;    [Condition of type UNBOUND-VARIABLE]
```

However, the query

```
(clsql:select 'dept_name
   :from 'dept)
```

returns all the department names in a list of one element `(dept_name)` lists.

I have declared a view class.

```
(clsql:def-view-class dept ()
  ((dept-id
    :db-kind :key
    :db-constraints :not-null
    :type integer
    :initarg :dept-id)
   (dept-name
    :accessor dept-name
    :type (string 10)
    :initarg :dept-name))
  (:base-table dept))
```

corresponding to the table `dept` with two attributes.

I have also enabled

```
(clsql:locally-enable-sql-reader-syntax)
```

I don't know what I am missing and how to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I think all my experiments were wrong. First, instead of using `(clsql:locally-enable-sql-reader-syntax)` we need to use `(clsql:enable-sql-reader-syntax)`. Locally is applicable only within a file. Please refer to this [comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/lisp/comments/o881be/clsql_a_simple_select_with_where_clause_is_not/) in Reddit Forum.